# Is there a way to get the x-axis coordinates of the left and right y axes when the x-axis is discrete in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The title sort of says it all. With continuous data on the x-axis this is relatively easy to solve. The issue arises when the x-axis is categorial or discrete. I'd like to place annotations near the left and right y-axis lines but it seems impossible to either find or set them. You can't set with `scale_x_discrete`. And `coord_cartesian` isn't any help with setting the limits. Further `layer_scales` doesn't extract that information.

For an example case, I want to put in line segments instead of full axes. Imagine doing the axes similar to base R's `plot`. It seems like `annotate` is the way to get there. For that I need x-coordinates. But if x is discrete the only thing that seems for sure is the locations of the individual items (1, 2, 3 etc.). The y-axis horizontal locations aren't set.

Comment: Are you trying to show the x-axis coordinates on the plot, or just get them from the data? To show them on the plot - have you tried `geom_text`?

Comment: This comment seems a bit off. I edited to give a use case but it's not the only one. That can make it a little more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know those limits if your aim is to annotate at the margin of the plot. Just use x = -Inf/Inf. (**PLOT 1**)

However, to your question: Discrete breaks always start at "1" and end at "Length of unique x". You need to add the panel expansion to those values: Thus, to get the axis limits, use 1-expansion and "Length of your unique x + expansion" (**PLOT2**). FYI, the default expansion for discrete axes is 0.6 (?scale_x_discrete).

If you decide to remove the expansion altogether, then the panel margins will be defined by the plotted elements. For example, the default width for the boxplot in my example seems to be something around 0.72 (trial and error, no reference here). This is a peculiar value and likely relative to the number of discrete breaks, therefore in this case I'd advise to manually define your boxplot width. (**PLOT 3 and 4**)

```r
library(ggplot2) 

ggplot(iris) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  annotate("text", c(-Inf, Inf), y = 4, label = letters[1:2], color = "red") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]

```r
expand_fac <- 0.6
xlims <- c(1-expand_fac, length(unique(iris$Species))+ expand_fac)

ggplot(iris) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  annotate("text", xlims, y = 4, label = letters[1:2], color = "red") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]

```r
expand_fac <- 0.36
xlims <- c(1-expand_fac, length(unique(iris$Species))+ expand_fac)

  ggplot(iris) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  annotate("text", xlims, y = 4, label = letters[1:2], color = "red") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]

```r
  
## without expansion better to define your aesthetic widths. 
expand_fac <- .5
  xlims <- c(1-expand_fac, length(unique(iris$Species))+ expand_fac)
  
  ggplot(iris) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(Species, Sepal.Length), width = 2*expand_fac) +
    annotate("text", xlims, y = 4, label = letters[1:2], color = "red") +
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
    coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This was incredibly useful for the use of the expand argument. I hadn't considered the x-axis in discrete situations mutable because you can't set the xlim in `scale_x_discrete`, and coord_cartesian seems useless in setting the axis as well, and so hadn't tried it. Also, the use of `Inf` to locate things on the axis was also handy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One option is just to just make the discrete x-axis variable numeric. If it's already a factor you can just use `as.numeric(myFactor)`. Then use the numeric version in your aesthetic mapping. This was always the way to handle doing pretty much anything interesting in base R plots. Then `scale_x_continuous` can be used to set the axis limits, breaks at the factor locations, and just add the labels with the factor. Everything would look the same as not doing the transform but the axis becomes more flexible and now you know the ends. But I should think ggplot2 would have a more direct way of handling this.